# Flink savepoint restarts my exactly-once sources (S3 and Kinesis) from the beginning every time

Tags: apache-flink

How can I manage to have savepoints start at the correct offset? I'm using the standard Kinesis sink and a continuous reader pointing to an S3 path.

I'm using exactly-once semantics (checkpointing) and I can verify that the sources's state is being stored with each savepoint.

Comment: Are you assigning UIDs properly? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/upgrading.html#matching-operator-state

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, every operator has a name and a UID which is the hash of that name.

Comment: Can you share logs for when you recover from savepoint?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov for example, the detail on the checkpoint tab in Flink's console?

Comment: How exactly are you reading from S3?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I'm using `environment.readFile` to with a continuous file processing mode. However, my plan is to consume the initial data from S3 and later enable Kinesis to continue processing in real-time.

Comment: Are you aware that with FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, when a file is modified, its contents are re-processed entirely? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes. I don't modify the files and only read  them once. The thing is  that if I use the other mode PROCESS_ONCE, after reading all the files the operator finishes and then I can't create any savepoints.

Answer (score 0):

> Under the hood, Flink splits the file reading process into two sub-tasks, namely directory monitoring and data reading. Each of these sub-tasks is implemented by a separate entity. ... The role of the single monitoring task is to scan the directory (periodically or only once depending on the watchType), find the files to be processed, divide them in splits, and assign these splits to the downstream readers. The readers are the ones who will read the actual data.

The monitoring function is in `ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction`, and it records into the snapshots the maximum file modification time seen so far for either the file or directory it is monitoring. And each of the `CheckpointableInputFormat`s for the file splits being read record their offsets.

Don't know why this isn't behaving as you expect, but as @YuvalItzchakov mentioned, there's helpful logging when this state is restored -- and even more so if you enable DEBUG level logging. Seeing these taskmanager logs might reveal what's going on.

If you are stuck and want to explore an alternative means of bootstrapping your state before switching to kinesis, you could use the state processor API to create a savepoint from the data in these files. Or you could use the state processor API to examine the state in the savepoints you already have.